# Split string using custom regex java

Tags: java, regex, string, split, compiler-construction

I am building a compiler. Some of the specifications of this are the following:

- String literals are enclosed by dollar sign ("$") - eg. $ string sample $
- Comments are enclosed by "*" - eg. * sample comment *
- Comments could exist anywhere execept between operations - eg. 4 + * sample comment * 5 - (this is not allowed)

Now I have to split a source code line to tokenize it.
Example case:

```
PRINT $ THE FLOAT IS $ * DISPLAY THE RESULT *
```

As I will tokenize it, it should produce:

```
PRINT - token is KEYWORD
THE FLOAT IS - token is STRING_LITERAL
DISPLAY THE RESULT - token is COMMENT
```

I would like to know the most efficient way to obtain this. Note that I still have to validate the occurence of string literal and comment. (Ex. Check if it is properly enclosed). So far my way is to split each line by whitespaces and and when a lexeme contains a "$" or "*", I will validate the string literal. Here is my implementation:

```
private void getLexemes(){
    for(String line : newSourceCode){
        String[] lexemesInALine = line.trim().split("[\\s]+");
        for(String lexemeInALine : lexemesInALine){
            if(!(lexemeInALine.contains("$"))){
                lexemes.add(lexemeInALine);
                tempTokens.add(findToken(lexemeInALine));
                line = line.replaceFirst(lexemeInALine,"").trim();
            }else{
                validateStringType(line);
                break;
            }
        }
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Are you interested in lexing by hand? There's a number of lexer / parser generators that you can use to concentrate on higher-level parts.

Comment: Yes. You got it. I am interested in lexing by hand.

Comment: But we are not allowed to use secondary libraries.

Comment: Not even [the standard library tokenizer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)?

Comment: I think we are allowed to use the standard library tokenizer. Let me check on that. Thank you.

Comment: `*` should be the comment delimiter... so what should be the multiplication operator? Or does the 3rd rule only applies for `+`s and `-`s?

Comment: Can you tell me, how to specifically used * as a comment delimeter? And in my compiler, it is not used as a multiplication operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your language is deterministic and context-free?
That means, you can't correctly parse it using regular expressions.

What you need is a state machine that works on a stream of tokens.
Java comes with two classes that might work for you: `StreamTokenizer` and `StringTokenizer`.

But what you really want is to use one of the dozens parser generators. Maybe something like ANTLR.
There are plenty described here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_parser_generators

If all this fails, a finite state machine it is.
Something along those lines

```
public class Parsy {
    enum State { string, comment, token }
    void parse(StringTokenizer tokenizer) {
        State state = State.token;

        List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<>();
        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String token = tokenizer.nextToken();
            // figure out type of token
            if (token.length() == 1) {
                char delim = token.charAt(0);
                switch (delim) {
                    case '$':
                        switch (state) {
                            case token: {
                                // a string literal has started, emit what we have, start a string
                                printOut(tokens, state);
                                tokens.clear();
                                tokens.add(token);
                                state = State.string;
                                break;
                            }
                            case string: { // parsing a string, so this ends it
                                printOut(tokens, state);
                                tokens.clear();
                                state = State.token;
                                break;
                            }
                            case comment: { // $ is ignored since we are in a comment
                                tokens.add(token);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    // ...
                }
            } else {
                // not a delimiter token
                tokens.add(token);
            }

        } // end of while
    if (state != State.token) {
       System.out.println("Oops! Syntax error. I'm still parsing" + state);
     }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not deterministic (I think) but YES, it is context-free thus I cannot use RE. I still have to read 'StreamTokenizer' and 'StringTokenizer' tho. Thank you for the link

Comment: By the way, we are not allowed to use secondary libraries in this project thus I cannot use other parser generators.

Comment: edit to outline on how to track state while parsing. `enum State` keeps track of where your parser's at: parsing a comment or a string or any other token

Comment: I think, the only limitation of this is I can't include validation while parsing since it directly "tokenize" the string. Not sure if I'm correct on this.

Comment: Such validation includes proper enclosing the String Literals and the Comments

Comment: if `state != State.token` that means you are still either trying to parse a comment or a string. 
so after `while` ends, check the `state` value. The parse is only successful if `state == State.token`

Note that I left out the other cases (i.e. you need to add case '*': by following the '$' example)